# Locating error cells in spreadsheet ranges

Tags: script, libreoffice-calc, user-interface

I have a large spreadsheet in which the minimum of one of the columns (containing formulæ) in a table shows an error (in this case `#DIV/0!`), and I would like a way to find the cell or cells in error satisfying these requirements:

- **General**: It should work for all sorts of errors that can occur in cells, e.g. `N/A` and numeric error codes.
- **Automatic**: I do not want to scan the entire column by hand and eye: almost all results are correct and they are many.
- **UI**: I would like to do this with the normal UI, possibly by adding one or two specific formulæ in a scratch area of the document.

  - *At a pinch a macro (see below under **Approaches**) would do, but it seems like overkill.*
- **Non-disruptive**: It should not be necessary to make major (perhaps error-prone) changes to the document.

##### Approaches

I have thought of the following approaches, which do not satisfy all my requirements:

- It would be possible to define a new column with the formula `=ISERROR(`*cell*`)` and a formula to find where in the new column the value `TRUE` occurs. This seems to me relatively **disruptive**.
- *(In my particular case I may be able to solve the problem by `MATCH`ing the value 0 in the column containing inputs to the formulæ, but that is obviously not **general**.
- Going beyond the **UI**, one could write a macro to scan the range, checking if the cells contain an error and perhaps positioning to the first one found. I do not know off-hand how to see if a cell contains an error, but I imagine that is fairly easy, perhaps a property of a cell object. If one made a function returning the address of the first error cell in a range, that would have the advantage of yielding a function that could be used in arbitrary sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LibreOffice Calc **Bugerra extension** was released over a year ago.

This extension adds a command to the Tools menu to generate a list of all errors in a document in natural order or by link count. The list shows the location of the cell, the error code, and the formula. It is displayed in a dialog box and can be inserted into a new document sheet.

[image: Bugerra Interface]

*Please note that the published version of the extension is marked "Beta" - this is a preliminary publication, which needs significant improvement. This gets the job done, but for spreadsheets with a very large number of errors, it takes a very long time without notifying the user of the progress of the process (so it looks like the program just hung). In addition, the idea expressed in the comment about finding errors only in a pre-selected range can significantly improve usability. Let's hope that future versions of this extension will be better.*

Comment: Thank-you for this, which sounds as though it meets my requirements, even if it scans the entire document rather than a specified range: that does not sound like a problem, if “In order” means by cell address, and if it is, inserting a new sheet would solve it. Does it treat N/A as an error? Does an extension like this come in the form of code that I can adapt it to my wishes?

Comment: @PJTraill Yes, sorry, you are right - the wording turned out to be extremely impolite. When publishing texts in a non-native language, I need to check the text twice and thrice to avoid embarrassing situations. Thanks for your pointing out, I've modified and added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is a better answer now. I have now installed Bugerra — and been able to see and learn something from your code, and also clear up a few problems in my sheet. Another improvement might be the chance to say whether or not N/A should be included (perhaps even a dialogue to choose which errors to check for, but I doubt that would be all that useful),